# Where does Ruby memory config go and how can one check if it is set?

Tags: ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

In REE, and MRI 1.9+, ruby's garbage collector can be tuned:

- http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_performance_tuning
- http://smartic.us/2010/10/27/tune-your-ruby-enterprise-edition-garbage-collection-settings-to-run-tests-faster/
- http://blog.evanweaver.com/articles/2009/04/09/ruby-gc-tuning/

But none of these articles say where to put this configuration. I imagine that if it's in the environment, ruby will pick it up when it starts -- however, there's no way to check this as far as I can tell. The settings don't show up in any runtime constants that I can find.

So, where do I put this configuration, and how can I double-check that it's being used?

Answer (score 1):

These settings are [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), so you would just need to set them in the parent process of the `ruby` process itself. [Many](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/06/13/fine-tuning-your-garbage-collector/) [people](http://snaprails.tumblr.com/post/241746095/rubys-gc-configuration) recommend creating a simple shell script for this purpose, perhaps calling it `/usr/local/bin/ruby-custom`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS=20000
export RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_INCREMENT=20000
...etc...
exec "/path/to/ruby" "$@"
```

The first few lines set whichever custom variables you want, and the last line invokes `ruby` itself, passing it whatever arguments this script was initially given.

You will next need to mark this script as executable (`chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/ruby-custom`) and then configure Passenger to use it as the `ruby` executable, by adding this to your Apache .conf file:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby-custom
```

Comment: thanks -- but what about the second question -- how can I double-check at runtime that the config has worked? (which is really my main question)

Comment: In Ruby 1.9+, you may be able to use [`GC.stat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC.html#method-c-stat) to inspect some of these settings. Also note that REE is [end-of-life](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/)